# Tem algum outro jeito de rodar meu mongodb sem ser pelo docker?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, docker

Recentemente, comecei com um projeto que utiliza mongodb, monitorado pelo Robo3t, porém, quando procuro uma informação na internet de como rodá-lo só aparecem explicações usando o Docker. Meu computador é 32 bits portanto não consigo instalá-lo. Se houver algum outro jeito de rodar o server na instalação natural pelo site, por favor me ajudem.

Comment: Tanto Docker quanto MongoDB só rodam em arquiteturas 64 bits. Se é para fim de aprendizagem, você pode criar uma conta gratuita no MongoDB Atlas e utilizar um banco de dados remoto nos seus projetos.

Comment: realmente, 32bit não irá rolar cara, além do MongoDB Atlas que o @user140828 comentou, tem também o Heroku e o Firebase, ambos são excelentes

Comment: Valeu pessoal, vou testar essas.

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

O MongoDB era compatível com Windows 32-bit até a versão 3.2 (inclusive). Portanto, é possível fazer download de uma versão anterior à 3.4 e instalá-la.

Download: https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386

Info sobre a quebra de compatibilidade: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms